# Views in ViewPager's Fragments are null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a MainActivity which contains the classic drawer layout, where drawer items are clicked and a fragment is loaded into the main container. On app load, my "MapFragment" is loaded into the container. This fragment contains a BottomSheet which contains a `ViewPager` which has 2 fragments.

If I load the app, and navigate away from the MapFragment, say a "SupportFragment", by clicking on a drawer item, that fragment gets loaded into the container. If I then navigate back to the MapFragment, all views in the fragments contained in the BottomSheet `ViewPager` are now null.

To clarify, the fragments in the `ViewPager` are not null, but all of their Views are.

Currently, the ViewPager is setup in the MapFragment's `onCreate()`, using the following code:

```
mBottomSheetViewPagerAdapter = new BottomSheetViewPagerAdapter(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager());
mFirstFragment = new FirstFragment();

mFirstFragment.setListener(new FirstFragmentListener() {
    //...listeners
});
mSecondFragment = new SecondFragment();
mSecondFragment.setListener(new SecondFragmentListener() {
    //...listeners
});

mBottomSheetViewPagerAdapter.add(mFirstFragment);
mBottomSheetViewPagerAdapter.add(mSecondFragment);

mViewPager.setAdapter(mBottomSheetViewPagerAdapter);
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Why might these views be null?

**EDIT:** So I found something rather interesting. I added log statements to the lifecycle methods of both the parent "MapFragment" and one of the Fragments in the `ViewPager` ("FirstFragment"). I noticed that on first launch of the MapFragment, I would see it's lifecycle methods printed, followed by those of the child fragment located in the `ViewPager`. When I navigated away, the MapFragment's `onPause()` and `onStop()` would be called, but nothing was printed from the child fragment in the `ViewPager`. When I then navigated back to the MapFragment by clicking on it's option in the drawer, I see the start up lifecycle methods from the MapFragment, but not the child fragment in the `ViewPager`.

If I refactor the child Fragments in the `ViewPager` to use native Fragments instead of support ones, and in turn the `ViewPager` adapter to extend from the v13 version of the FragmentPagerAdapter, I then pass in `getChildFragmentManager` when instantiating my adapter: `mBottomSheetViewPagerAdapter = new BottomSheetViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());`

This has the interesting effect of the missing lifecycle methods from the child fragment in the `ViewPager` being run, and thus their corresponding log statements printed. To illustrate all of this, here is a summary of what is printed to logcat when launching the app, navigating to a different fragment, and then navigating back to the original one:

***With Support Fragments:***

```
//App launched, default MapFragment loaded
MapFragment onCreate() 
MapFragment onCreateView()
MapFragment onStart() 
MapFragment onResume() 
FirstFragment onCreate() called
FirstFragment onCreateView() called.
FirstFragment onStart() called.
FirstFragment onResume() called.

//Navigate to another fragment
MapFragment onPause() 
MapFragment onStop() 

//Use the drawer to navigate back to the MapFragment
MapFragment onCreateView()
MapFragment onStart() 
MapFragment onResume()
```

***With Native Fragments***

```
//App launched, default MapFragment loaded
MapFragment onCreate() 
MapFragment onCreateView()
MapFragment onStart() 
MapFragment onResume() 
FirstFragment onCreate() called
FirstFragment onCreateView() called.
FirstFragment onStart() called.
FirstFragment onResume() called.

//Navigate to another fragment
FirstFragment onPause() called.
MapFragment onPause() 
FirstFragment onStop() called
MapFragment onStop() 

//Use the drawer to navigate back to the MapFragment
MapFragment onCreateView()
FirstFragment onCreateView() called.
MapFragment onStart() 
FirstFragment onStart() called.
MapFragment onResume() 
FirstFragment onResume() called.
```

However, even when explicitly seeing that the child fragments onCreateView() is being called on the second time around, if I try to access any of the views (in this case, calling a method which calls `setFocusable()` on an `EditText`), I get a NPE.

Comment: Because they aren't initialized

Comment: @LunarWatcher Can you elaborate? They are initialized just fine on first load of the "MapFragment".

Comment: From what I see in the code snippet, mViewPager and mTabLayout are never initialized.

Comment: They are bound at the top of the class via Butterknife.

Comment: oh. Never mind then